# React and Redux: Patch Method in the right way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying for a while to do a patch method.

I have tried to test my rest server with Postman(or other similar apps) and it works, so the problem is not from the php side but from the js side. (I am newby about this world.)

I have explored the code in postman to see if I pass data in a wrong format, but they aren't (I used FormData).

So I think that the problem is about the Actions.js or Reducers.js part.

Anyway, in my reducers.js

```
export const reducer = (state = [] , action) => {
    switch(action.type){    
        case 'MEETING_PATCH':
            return {...state, changeMeeting: action.changeMeeting};
        default: 
            return state;
    }

}

export default reducer;
```

My Actions.js

```
export const patchMeeting = (idmeeting, changeMeeting) => {
    console.log(...changeMeeting);
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(
                myapiRoute + "/" + idmeeting, {
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    body: changeMeeting,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((response) => console.log(response.json()))
            .then((changeMeeting) => {
                console.log(changeMeeting);
                dispatch({
                    type: "MEETING_PATCH",
                    changeMeeting: changeMeeting,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("An error occurred.", error));
    };
};
```

While in the page in which I have the form after the submit of data:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let idmeeting = this.state.meeting_id;
    let formdata = new FormData();

    if(typeof this.state.changeMeeting.meeting.meeting_motivation !== "undefined")
    {
      formdata.append("meeting_motivation", this.state.changeMeeting.meeting.meeting_motivation);  
    }

    if(typeof this.state.changeMeeting.meeting.date !== "undefined")
    {
      formdata.append("date", this.state.changeMeeting.meeting.date);  
    }

    this.props.patchMeeting(idmeeting, formdata);
  }
```

I really don't understand where is the problem.

When I try to submit data I receive these errors:

> Access to fetch at '' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> PATCH myapiRoute net::ERR_FAILED

I know that this is not a cors problem, because I have fixed it (infact I can do post, get). For example this errors appears in the post when I insert something wrong in the fetch.

How can I do this patch method?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The api server has to enable CORS or you have to use proxying in react for development https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: @MjZac As I wrote I have enabled the cors in the api server. It is not a CORS problem :(

Comment: Okay, do you have the `PATCH` method in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:` ?

Comment: Yes I have it :( `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');`

Comment: But did you think that my code is right?

Comment: Yes, code looks fine. This should be related to CORS, try proxying the request and if that works, then it definitely is a CORS issue.